# Example for partition $ \prod = \{ x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n \} $ of $ [a,b] $ where $ \max\{ | x_i - x_{i-1} | : i = 1,...,n \} < \delta $

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

Sometimes when I'm doing proofs regrading Riemann Integrals I would like to create an explicit parition whose norm is less than $ \delta $ . I'm familiar with creating the following partition of $ [a,b] $ : $ \prod = \{ a < a+\frac{a}{b-a}<a+\frac{2a}{b-a} <...<a+\frac{i\cdot a}{b-a} < ....< a+\frac{n \cdot a}{b-a}  \} $ here the mesh of partition is $ \max\{ | x_i - x_{i-1} | : i = 1,...,n \} = \frac{a}{b-a}  $

But I would like an example for a partition $ \prod = \{ x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n \} $ of $ [a,b] $ whose mesh satisfies $ \max\{ | x_i - x_{i-1} | : i = 1,...,n \} < \delta $ ( where $ \delta > 0 $ ). ( In the above example, if $ a \neq 0 $ then it doesn't necessarily mean that $ \frac{a}{b-a} < \delta $, but I can't think of an example for a partition that can satisfy of mesh being less than $ \delta $  )
Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit ( + solution as given in the comments ):**
I made a mistake in the partition above, Here's an example for a correct partition of $[a,b] $:
$ \prod = \{ a < a+\frac{1\cdot (b-a)}{n}<a+\frac{2\cdot (b-a)}{n} <...<a+\frac{i\cdot (b-a)}{n} < ....< a+\frac{n\cdot (b-a)}{n} = b  \} $
Now, as stated in the comments, looking at the mesh of this partition, it is $ \frac{b-a}{n} $ and I want $  \frac{b-a}{n} < \delta  $ so I see that $ \frac{b-a}{\delta} < n $. So we'll choose $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $ \frac{b-a}{N} < \delta $ ( the argument for this is by Archimedean Principle ), thus, if I want to create a partition of mesh less than $  \delta $ I can create the following partition of $ [a,b] $:
$ \tilde{\prod}  = \{ a < a+\frac{1\cdot (b-a)}{N}<a+\frac{2\cdot (b-a)}{N} <...<a+\frac{i\cdot (b-a)}{N} < ....< a+\frac{N\cdot (b-a)}{N} = b  \}  $ and the mesh of this partition is $ \frac{b-a}{N} < \delta $, as wanted.

Comment: let $n$ be an integer such that $\frac{b-a}{n}<\delta$ this exists by Archimedian property. Take your partition to be $x_i=a+i\cdot \frac{b-a}{n}$

Comment: So silly of me, I keep forgetting to utilize Archimedean property. I even now noticed that my partition is somewhat not correct but should be $ \prod = \{ a < a+\frac{1\cdot (b-a)}{n}<a+\frac{2\cdot (b-a)}{n} <...<a+\frac{i\cdot (b-a)}{n} < ....< a+\frac{n\cdot (b-a)}{n} = b  \} $, that's why I couldn't figure out the correct conditions for making such a partition as I've wanted . Very nice!

Comment: Yes, indeed. Good you noticed!

Comment: @hazelnut_116 You should edit your question and give a correct partition.

Comment: Ok, i'll do that